# Incorrect result of grand total in crystal report using insert summary

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Left row in picture is giving a correct result but other row is not giving a correct sum. Why?

[image]

Comment: Please post some of your code or configuration.

Comment: Give us more info? Are all the rows produced from the same field? And how is the sum produced? By summary or by formula? And what type of summary or what is the code of formula?

Comment: Where did you choose for summary location?